# Transcendance in function fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Denote by $\Omega$ the completion of an algebraic closure of $\mathbb F_q\left(\!\left(\frac1T\right)\!\right)$ for the valuation $-\deg$. Let $(a_n)_n$ be a sequence of $\overline{\mathbb F_q(T)}\subset\Omega$ such that $a_n\ne0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, and such that
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\limits \deg(a_n)=+\infty.$$  Consider the entire function on $\Omega$ defined by $$f(z)=\prod_{n\ge0}\left(1-\frac z{a_n}\right).$$ Can one assert that for every $$u\in\overline{\mathbb F_q(T)}\setminus\{a_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\},$$ we have $$f(u)\notin\overline{\mathbb F_q(T)}?$$

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: What if $a_n = T^n$ or otherwise lies in $\mathbb F_q((1/T))$, and $z$ lies in $\mathbb F_q((1/T))$, then won't the product obviously lie in $\mathbb F_q((1/T))$?

Comment: sorry. I read again my question. There is a problem. I edit it.

Comment: This obviously won't work either. You can fix $z$ and a target $c$ in $\overline{\mathbb F_q(T)}$ and choose $a_n$ so that the partial product $\prod_{n\geq 0} (1- \frac{z}{a_n})$ is within $T^n$, say, of $c$.

Comment: What do you mean by "within $T^n, say, of $c$" ?

Comment: Sorry that was unclear. I mean $ \deg (\prod_{n=0}^m (1- \frac{z}{a_n} )  - c ) \leq m$. It's easy to see that you can always choose $a_m$ satisfying that if $a_0,\dots, a_{m-1}$ do and you will have $\deg(a_n)\to\infty$ if you do.

Comment: This is still not quite right unfortunately, I mean the degree is $\leq -m$.